# How to use rvm (ruby version manager) with root account?

Tags: root, rvm

The whole point of rvm is to be able to install multiple rubies and access them from a user account. What do you do when you need to access any of those rubies from root? Or use gems installed in one of those rvms?

Is there an elegant (or even hackish) way to use these I haven't considered?

My guess is that I should just add it to my PATH, but I'm curious if anyone has come up with a better idea. I'd rather not install rvm just for the root account and duplicate everything.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found the solution:

[rvmsudo](https://rvm.io/integration/sudo) does the trick.

Comment: `rvmsudo` does in fact work, but the provided URL does not contain any info about it anymore...

Answer (score 10):

System wide install is no longer exist.

Use this command in Ubuntu console to install rvm as root and be available for all users:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash
```

Answer (score 6):

Though, I am little late, you don't really have to use rvmsudo. Just make sure that you have .rvm directory and its structure created inside your home directory. Then, each of rvm command will do respective installations on user's home directory.

You can achieve this by simply running following command.

```
rvm user all
```

Reference, https://rvm.io/rvm/install/ (MultiUser installation)

Comment: This solves the problem for me with Oracle Linux and RVM. Need MultiUser installation.

Answer (score 2):

This may help: http://rvm.io/deployment/ (updated) (EDIT: the instructions might be broken)

Comment: @davej: Link is broken (again)